# TypeError: moment.preciseDiff is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, momentjs

TypeError: moment.preciseDiff is not a function
I am getting the same error....is there any remedy or alternaitve.

I am using moment @2.24.0

```
moment-precise-range-plugin
```

, I have also tied with latest one(2.29.0)

my main code statement is

```
const diff = moment.preciseDiff(firstDate, secondDate, true);
```

and I am expecting output as :

```
{years : 0, months : 1, days : 2, hours : 3, minutes : 4, seconds : 5, firstDateWasLater : false}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and this will work for sure:

```
const moment = require('moment');
require('moment-precise-range-plugin');

const firstDate = moment('2022-01-01');
const secondDate = moment('2022-02-03');

const diff = secondDate.preciseDiff(firstDate);
console.log(diff);
```